# Integrity constraint violation - Not null violation

Tags: postgresql

Looking for some help here - I'm working on a site that is using a PostgreSQL db and am running into an issue. When saving a large Matrix field with multiple block types I was receiving the following error:

```
Integrity constraint violation
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

At first, I thought there was something corrupted with the Matrix so I nuked it and rebuilt it - everything seemed to be working fine until I created a new channel section - when I tried to create an entry there, I got the following error:

```
Integrity constraint violation
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO "drafts" ("sourceId", "creatorId", "name", "notes") VALUES (NULL, 5772, 'First draft', NULL)).
```

Similar to the above, just a new table this time.

Everything I am reading points to an auto-increment issue, though in both cases there does seem to be the appropriate sequence in the db. I've barely used PostgreSQL and never with Craft, though I'm not 100% certain it has to do with the db.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Comment: It definitely seems like that table is missing the sequence that creates the integers for the id column. If you do a database dump, do you see them in the output?

Comment: Brad, there's a sequence being created for entrydrafts but not for drafts. Also, while I'm not sure it matters, there are a few entries in the drafts table with NULL sourceId values.

Answer (score 0):

> there's a sequence being created for entrydrafts but not for drafts.

That's your issue.

I did a fresh Craft 3.3. install on PostgreSQL and there should be a `drafts_id_seq` sequence created for the `drafts` table that you're missing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Brad. I ended up nuking the entire environment and starting over. I had imported a database from a server running PostgreSQL 11 into a vagrant box running 9.6 - after importing into a new box running the same version everything seems to have sorted itself out. Thanks!